# how do i show html select above the other elements

Tags: html, css

I have a registration page, in which I have a phone field, when I select that field the popup show underneath the other elements.

> > I want to know that why the phone field options are shown underneath the below options?

> Please refer: [image: the output image]

> The code that I am using for:

1. sign-up.jsp

   ```
           <form action="Controller" method="GET" id="form">
           <input type="hidden" name="command" value="registration"/>
           <table class="sign-up-div-table">
               <tr>
                   <td colspan="2"> <h3>Join us for free</h3> </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                   <td> <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required/> </td>
                   <td> <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" pattern="^[A-Z][-a-zA-Z]+$" placeholder="Last name" required/> </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                   <td colspan="2"> <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required  onkeyup="check(this.value)"/> </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                   <td colspan="2"> <div id = "mydiv"></div> </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                   <td colspan="2"> <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required/> </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                   <td> <jsp:include page="demo.html"></jsp:include> </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                   <td colspan="2"> <div id = "numberdiv"></div> </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                   <td colspan="2">
                       <div class="input-group input-group-xs">
                           <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 100px; background-color:#a2a587; color: white;" >Birthday</span>
                           <select name="date" class="form-control" style="background-color: #c7cca7;" required>
                               <option disabled selected value> select date </option>
                               <jsp:include page="dates.jsp"></jsp:include>
                           </select>

                           <select name="month" class="form-control" style="background-color: #c7cca7;" required>
                               <option disabled selected value> select month </option>
                               <jsp:include page="months.jsp"></jsp:include>
                           </select>

                           <select name="year" class="form-control" style="background-color: #c7cca7;" required>
                               <option disabled selected value> select year </option>
                               <jsp:include page="years.jsp"></jsp:include>
                           </select>

                       </div>
                   </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                   <td colspan="2">
                       <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                           <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 100px;">Gender</span>
                           <select class="form-control" name="gender" style="width: 300px;" required>
                               <option disabled selected value> select gender </option>
                               <option>male</option>
                               <option>female</option>
                               <option>other</option>
                           </select>
                       </div>
                   </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                   <td colspan="2">
                       <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                           <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 100px;">Position</span>
                           <select class="form-control" name="position" style="width: 300px;" required>
                               <option disabled selected value> select position </option>
                               <option>Writer</option>
                               <option>Author</option>
                               <option>Contributor</option>
                               <option>Teacher</option>
                               <option>Student</option>
                           </select>
                       </div>
                   </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                   <td colspan="2" align="left"> <input type="submit" value="Get Started" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"/> </td>
                   <td></td>
               </tr>

           </table>
       </form>
   ```

Comment: that's not an html <select>; it's a whole lot of other HTML+CSS+JS. show the output please.

Comment: @dandavis that's the output

Comment: as seen by the client, not the server; `<jsp:include` et al is not html... <select> doesn't do color or graphics, so we know there's more than meets the eye here.

Comment: this one I am using: https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input#getting-started

Comment: you are asking _why the phone field options are shown underneath the below options?_ and you shared an html that didn't include the phone field. Anyway that's usually something related with the `z-index`. Maybe the fields: date, month, year have a `z-index` set that happens to be higher than what the nationality options layer is supposed to be

Comment: this question was asked years ago and for some reason was edited few minutes ago and that's why it reached my attention.. it was pointless to comment now